# Golang JSON Unmarshal serialized number

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have a question about json.Unmarshal.
Playground example https://play.golang.org/p/3d0nUv7PSJ

The problem is: JSON does not unmarshal "1" to float. I mean "1" is a serialized JSON which should be a number. Am I doing something wrong ?:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSON, `"1"` is a string. If you use `1` in your example instead, it's properly unmarshalled as a float.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/60symMsRSW

Comment: But `"1"` is a `serialized` JSON String

Comment: Correct. I'm not sure what you want here. `"1"` is a string, so it's unmarshalled as a string. If you want a float, you'll need to unmarshal a number (e.g. `1`).

Comment: For example: a:=1; Marshal > `"1"` - this is a `marshalled` integer. I want to pass a `"1"` for unmarshalling - and I expect `float`.

Comment: If you marshal `1`, you'll get a string with the value `1`. If you then unmarshal it, you'll get a float with the value `1`.

Comment: But a `marshalled` variable is a byte array which looks like `"1"`. Unmarshal returns `string` :D

Comment: This is wrong. Why do you believe this? (Can you provide an example program that incorrectly marshals `1` to `"1"`?)

Comment: Hopefully this example convinces you: https://play.golang.org/p/AshMpW1byH.

Comment: The example is: Python code makes a serialization to variable as a string. https://s14.postimg.org/vea8dpdht/Screen_Shot_2016_08_21_at_23_05_00.png)](https://postimg.org/image/wtbt2fekt/. So I receive a multipart from python

Comment: JSON is always a string. The string contains `1` (not `"1"`).

Comment: Looks like I was mistaken. http://requestb.in/174wtf01?inspect. Just sent a value with serialized and got response. Next time I'll send to requestb.in before asking :D Thanks for your time :D